# How to speed up the filling of a network-matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, ggplot2

I want to plot a network using ggnet with ggplot2
https://briatte.github.io/ggnet/

I have a dataframe that consists of the interconnection between 100 nodes:

```
node.start=trunc(runif(n=100,min=1,max=100))
node.end=trunc(runif(n=100,min=1,max=100))
d <- data.frame( node.start, node.end )

node.start node.end
1          3
1          5
3          5
3          5
...
100        46
```

In order to use ggnet I need a network matrix like

```
      [1]  [2]  ... [100]
[1]    2    5
[2]    4    0
...
[100]
```

A brute dummy solution would be to loop twice over each node:

```
net <- matrix( nrow=NA, ncol=NA )
for( i in 1:100 ){
for( j in i:100 ){
ij <- length(which(d$node.start == i) & which(d$node.end == j) )
net[i,j] <- ij
}
}
```

But that takes ages, and I want to apply it later on a network with 400+ nodes.
Do you know any way to speed up that process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `igraph` package to convert to a network object and then back to an adjacency matrix.

Working with a smaller example to increase the number of repeated pairs:

```
set.seed(6932)
node.start=trunc(runif(n=100,min=1,max=10))
node.end=trunc(runif(n=100,min=1,max=10))
d <- data.frame( node.start, node.end )
library(igraph)
net <- as_adj(graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(d)),sparse = F)
```

Which returns:

```
> net
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    4    1    2    1    0    2    1    1    0
 [2,]    2    2    0    2    0    0    5    2    1
 [3,]    1    2    1    0    1    2    0    3    1
 [4,]    2    0    3    1    1    1    2    1    0
 [5,]    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    1    0
 [6,]    1    1    4    0    2    2    0    3    1
 [7,]    1    0    2    1    1    3    0    0    0
 [8,]    1    0    3    1    4    0    5    0    1
 [9,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    0    2    0
```

If you want to get the sum, such that [i,j] = [i,j]+[j,i] = [j,i], add this line: `as_adj(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(net,mode="plus"),sparse = F)`

Comment: I see, but this solution does not count as many times the combinations occur. In my example the combination (3,5) occurs twice, but the matrix element is d[3,5] = 1

Comment: Hm. As it is, it should count the number of times pairs are repeated in each[ [i,j,] cell, at least for the `igraph` example. I'll revise to make it clear.